# paypal useraction=commit doesnt give a pay button. PHP

Tags: php, paypal

I have the following code in php

```
        $postData = "USER=xxxxxx"
            . "&PWD=xxxxxxxx"
            . "&SIGNATURE=xxxxxxx"
            . "&METHOD=SetExpressCheckout"
            . "&VERSION=93"
            . "&EMAIL=" . $_POST['email']
            . "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOPHONENUM=" . $_POST['phone']
            . "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=" . $price
            . "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT=" . $price
            . "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION=SALE"
            . "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC=" . $plan['fullname']
            . "&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0=" .$plan['fullname']
            . "&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0=$price"
            . "&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0=1"
            . "&RETURNURL=http://localhost/bemo/casperreg"
            . "&CANCELURL=http://bemoacademicconsulting.com/casperprep-internal";

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); // this line makes it work under https
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);

        // Ready the postData to send
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);

        // Send the data to Paypal and assign the repsonse
        $resp = curl_exec($ch);
        parse_str($resp,$arr);

        redirect::to("https://www.paypal.com/checkoutnow?token=" . $arr['TOKEN'] . "&useraction=commit");
```

Now technically everything here works except for the fact that even though it says useraction=commit I don't get a pay now button. Can anyone help me please?

Also as a bonus question, even though I pass the phone number to paypal, I don't see it on the paypal page. Is this something I can do?

Thanks!
Nur

Comment: try ("https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&useraction=commit&token=". $arr['TOKEN']) instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct redirect address for express checkout should be
`https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&useraction=commit&token=[token number]`
Source: [Developer Guide](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECCustomizing/)

As to your bonus question
1. Try doing a field mask on number xxx-xxx-xxxx
2. Check if phone number is set to required in your merchant profile

Comment: Thank you very much! Your address is the correct one indeed.

so no phone number unless it's required? will do

Comment: I think it doesn't pull the data unless phone number is set to required in the merchant profile. It used to be the way for the deprecated `PHONENUM` paramter not 100% sure if it is the same for `PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOPHONENUM`

Comment: and if I remember correctly, if the payer has a phone number stored in his/her profile, the system won't pull the phone number from the post data either. Unfortunately such things aren't well covered by the developer guide. You would need to do some trial and error testings, and when you do find out, it would be helpful to post the info as an answer to your own question for those who visit your post at a later day in search for solution.

Comment: Actually, you can email your account manager and ask to have the question pass onto the development team, paypal has excellent CS. They have been rather helpful when I contacted them in the past.

Comment: Hi, I will post more about this when I learn more info. Thanks for the answer!